# Semaphore bulk sms

Tags: php, sms

I Know this is easy for you guys but cann you help me? I'm just starting in web deve and i having a hard time sending build sms the error say

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '--' (T_DEC) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Send SMS\send bulk sms using semaphore\bulk.php on line 8"

[click here to see the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDVOR.png)]

Comment: The code you show is trying to use a command line curl request in PHP.  You will need to convert this to PHP's curl library. The duplicate shows SOME parts of this, so have a read around using PHP and curl and see how far you can get.  Come back if you have a new problem (with a new question if necessary).

Comment: OMG I'M sO F*CKING DUMB. Thanks you so much it work. I beenworking on this for 3 days.How do i repay you?

Comment: Be more prepared to ask (even what you may think are dumb) questions.  It stops a lot of frustration and means you can enjoy coding more.